# Ruby Regex extract parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, date, format

I have a date in this format

```
11/28/2011 2:39:00 PM
```

I cant seem to get a way to extract to each element out of this format (like take out day, month, year, hour, minute, second, AM/PM) separately to work with them. I need help here, so i can use this to rearrange the time manually and work with it how i want. I cant find a solution for this. (but im pretty sure i would need to use regex)

Comment: Have you tried doing anything yourself already? It might help to post what you've tried and what's not working.

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems." -Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I'm sure regex isn't the best way to do it, here are some regex's that I tested on [rubular.com](http://rubular.com)!

Month:

```
(\d){2}(?=\/\d\d\/)
```

Day:

```
(\d){2}(?=\/\d\d\d\d)
```

Year:

```
(\d){4}(?=\s)
```

Hour:

```
(\d){1,2}(?=:\d\d:\d\d\s)
```

Minute:

```
(\d){2}(?=:\d\d\s)
```

Second:

```
(\d){2}(?=\s\w\w\b)
```

AM/PM:

```
\b[PA]M\b
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason for all these lookaheads?

Comment: Maybe not!  I'm still trying to figure out regex's.

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'date'
str = '11/28/2011 2:39:00 PM'
date = DateTime.strptime(str, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
puts date.year # etc
```

Comment: this might be nitpicking but the 2:39:00 PM comes out to just 00:00:00 +0000, which isn't really good. For my purposes, i only need accuracy within a day, so this is fine, but i can't say yours is right, i might say the chronic answer

Comment: Eh... Fixed it for you. I used `Date` class instead of `DateTime`. But you said you wanted a "date", so I figured `Date` would be probably more correct.

Comment: nice, sorry but i have to choose bodoz's answer, because his answer solves the way the question asked (but im gonna use your's in my app)

Answer (score 1):

I've found it easiest to use the Chronic gem to do this kind of parsing. Chronic handles these a lot better than the default DateTime stuff:

```
gem install chronic
```

And then:

```
require 'chronic'
date = Chronic.parse(my_date)
puts "year, month, day, hour: #{date.year}, #{date.month}, #{date.day}, #{date.hour}"
```

Etc.

Comment: I generally dislike date parsing heuristics, and either make sure my locale is well defined or explicitly specify the format, since I never know what 11/12/2011 comes out to. Actually, I wish everyone would just embrace the Japanese and UTC way of doing things - putting year at the end is completely illogical in context of how our number system works. I'd love Chronic if it wasn't for silly Americans and their mm/dd/yyyy :)

Comment: @Amadan, I agree, but parsing is valuable when you're trying to interpret user input, and don't want to force them to use a preferred format. That's where chronic shines.

Comment: I see that - it really is cool. I am just scared of cases when `day_of_month <= 12`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to parse it with regular expression, you can simply convert into DateTime:

```
require 'date'
my_time = DateTime.parse('11/28/2011 2:39:00 PM')
puts my_time.day  # and so on
```

Comment: Well, then use `DateTime.strptime`

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.strptime http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime to create a DateTime object and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this naive regex:

```
/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\s(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\s(\w+)/
```

If your format never changes, ever, at all...